# strict MIME type checking is enabled issue with PGAdmin in Azure application gateway

Tags: kubernetes, ingress, aks, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to install pgAdmin (image: 'dpage/pgadmin4:6.21') in Azure AKS. I am able to access the application when I use a Kubernetes LoadBalancer service, but when I use an Azure Application Gateway with Ingress, the login page is displayed without an issue. However, after login, it gets stuck on the loading page.

[image]

When I checked the browser console, I found the following error:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://somedomain.xyz.cloudapp.azure.com/pgadmin4/login?next=%2Fpgadmin4%2Fbrowser%2F' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I am almost certain that the issue is not related to the pgAdmin installation as it is already working with the Kubernetes LoadBalancer service. I have found some workarounds to get rid of the loading page by adding some lines in the pgAdmin scripts (as it assumes pgAdmin has a bug), but I have been unsuccessful in implementing these workarounds.

I have also tried changing the Ingress configuration without any success. Is there any recommendation or a way to trace the issue and find the root cause?"

ingress implementation :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/appgw-ssl-certificate: "devaks-cert"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/cookie-based-affinity: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /pgadmin4/*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: pgadmin
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a similar setup where Azure Application Gateway is in front of pgadmin deployed on AKS, and updating the following config resolves the issue for us, created extra file with the name `config_distro.py`

```
  X_CONTENT_TYPE_OPTIONS = ""    # default value is nosniff
  ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION = False
  X_XSS_PROTECTION = "0"  # default value is '1; mode=block'
```

For detailed description of these config check below URL
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/config_py.html